# I have a current google analytics code on my website and I can not figure out how to access the information.

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

My website was built for me so it does not correspond with my gmail account. What do I do with code to find out the details of my account?

Comment: Normally you log into https://www.google.com/analytics/  with a Google account. If you do not have that log in info, contact the developer that put the code in for you.

Answer (score 0):

The script use an identifier to connect to a specific account. You can either just log into analytics and change the ID on your site to your own or ask the guy who made the site if he/her have already made an account.

The line you have to change looks something like:

```
ga(‘create’, ‘UA-XXXX-Y’, ‘auto’);
```

Where UA-XXXX-Y is your Google Analytics tracking ID.